# What is the difference between MATSEQMAIJ and MATSEQAIJ in PETSc?

Tags: matrix, petsc

What is the difference between MATSEQMAIJ and MATSEQAIJ in PETSc?

Also, where can I find more information on each of the MatTypes? I went to the [MatType](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatType.html) documentation, but it didn't have anything but the definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MATMAIJ](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MATMAIJ.html) is a matrix type that is mostly used to represent interpolation/restriction operators in multigrid methods. It represents the Kronecker product of a sparse matrix with a small block identity, so that all fields associated with a given discretization node are interpolated in the same way, without needing any redundant storage.